# how to add a view without adding an action method in the controller in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a reasonably big MVC website and in the middle of a sprint we have to  deploy a view containing static text. The current state of the website is not ready for live deployment and we need to do a lot of testing before its ready. Can we possibly deploy this view without adding an action method in the controller directly on the webserver. e.g. the new view name is `Policy.cshtml` it resides in `Views/Home/` folder and we want to add an anchor link to the footer of a the layout view like

```
<a href="/home/Policy">Policy</a>
```

Comment: Why don't you just make a controller with an index actionmethod that returns this view? Controllers serve the views in MVC.

Answer (score 2):

A solution to bypass controllers is to enable **Web Pages** in **web.config** :

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Then you can easily access a page without typing the action name

With **Hello.cshtml** at root of your site, you can access it with :

```
 http://localhost:59051/Hello
 or
 http://localhost:59051/Hello.cshtml
```

But take care, you can't by default access directly to views under Views directory.

Reference:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-pages/overview/getting-started/aspnet-web-pages-razor-faq

Regards

Answer (score 1):

In MVC Framework, the controller class includes a method `HandleUnknownAction()` that executes whenever we attempt to invoke an action (or when we request a view which has no matching action method) on a controller that does not exist.

```
protected override void HandleUnknownAction(string actionname)
{
  this.View(actionname).ExecuteResult(this.ControllerContext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All request must be passed in controller.
You can add Fake Action or render view on current page. And you can show/hide this div by means of javascript.

```
<a href="javascript:" id="PolicyLink">Policy</a>
<div id ="Policy" style="display:none;">
    @Html.Partial("Policy")
</div>
<script>
    $("#PolicyLink").on("click",function()
    {
      $("#Policy").show();
    });
</script>
```